# Building UCB logo 6 - errors in mathcalls.h

Tags: compiling, gcc

After hearing of [Seymour Papert](https://www.media.mit.edu/people/in-memory/papert)'s passing, I wanted to install [Berkeley Logo (UCBLogo)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html). The Ubuntu repos only have v5.5.

After downloading and extracting the archive, working out its dependencies (seemingly `libbsd-dev libx11-dev build-essential libwxgtk3.0-dev libtinfo-dev texinfo texlive`) and running `./configure`, running `make` gives these errors:

```
gcc -g -O   -O0 -DUSE_OLD_TTY   -c -o coms.o coms.c
In file included from coms.c:30:0:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:100:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘extern’
 __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
 ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:100:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘extern’
 __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
 ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:100:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘extern’
 __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
 ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'coms.o' failed
make: *** [coms.o] Error 1
```

The package builds properly on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian, gcc 4.9.2, armv7l) but not on this machine  (Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0, x86_64). I wouldn't have expected errors generated *inside* system include files. The mathcalls.h header looks quite different on the two systems, with the error lines calling a different macro. Could this be a gcc-4 to gcc-5 issue?

Comment: As an update, I don't have a solution to this, but someone in the local LUG took a good look at the code and came up with some potential mitigations: [[GTALUG] Ubuntu 16.04 / gcc 5.4.0 - errors generated inside system include files](https://gtalug.org/pipermail/talk/2016-August/003922.html "[GTALUG] Ubuntu 16.04 / gcc 5.4.0 - errors generated inside system include files"). Essentially, the code redefines **exp** for its own purposes, when it's the nearest thing to a reserved word that the C language can have.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out how to compile this code:

- In `coms.c` and in `graphics.c` move the line `include <math.h>` to before the line `include "logo.h"`
- After running `.configure` open up the file `makefile` and change the call to the library `-ltermcap` with `-lncurses`.

Then you can run `make` and it should compile OK.

One thing I haven't worked out is how to compile with the wx toolkit.  I have the libraries on my system, but both `.configure` and `make` seem to ignore it.